# How to solve this entropy integral?

Tags: homework, matrix, information-theory

I am having the entropy integral below where $\mathbf x$ is a $N$ dimensional Gaussian vector having variance as $\mathbf P$ and mean zero,

$$ -\int\frac {\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbf x^T\mathbf P^{-1}\mathbf x\right)}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}|\mathbf P|^{\frac{1}{2}}}\log_2\left(\frac {\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbf x^T \mathbf P^{-1}\mathbf x\right)}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}| \mathbf P|^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right) d\mathbf x$$

How do I solve this integral ? My approach is,  let

$$
\mathbf x=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2}  \\
    \vdots\\
    x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad \mathbf P=\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{1} & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    0 & \sigma_{2} & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & \sigma_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am getting an integral like
$$-\displaystyle\int \frac {\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_1^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\ldots+\frac{x_n^2}{\sigma_n^2}\right)\right)}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}|\mathbf P|^{\frac{1}{2}}}\log_2\left(\frac {\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_1^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\ldots +\frac{x_n^2}{\sigma_n^2}\right)\right)}{{(2\pi)}^{\frac{1}{2}}|\mathbf P|^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right) d\mathbf x$$ 
but I am confused how to do this $d\mathbf x$ stuff when $\mathbf x$ is a vector. Am I doing it right?

The answer given is

> $$\frac{n}{2}\log_2(2 \pi e)+ \frac {1}{2}\log_2|\mathbf P|$$

Comment: This is more appropriate for [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/). And [cross-posting is not appreciated on SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), you have  [this same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084433/how-to-solve-this-integral-in-which-matrices-are-involved) there as well.

Comment: I still don't get the answer on math.se, and this is one of the time when specific problems related both to mathematics and a particular field is not answered in mathematics. You can still check for no answer for this in mathematics website. Though I agree that it is not right upto an extent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integration over a vector $\mathbf x$ as given by you means something like

$$\int f(\mathbf x) d\mathbf x=\int\dots\int f(x_1,\dots,x_n)dx_1\dots dx_n$$

So, you integrate over each component separately. Now, to solve your integral, you should first split the $\log$ into a difference and evaluate both integrals separately (exploiting the fact that $\exp(ab)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$. Then you will get a lot of similarly structured integrals that depend only on $\sigma_i$. If you solve them, you'll get the solution.